# Assign Static IP To Container or Serverless Solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ip

i am new to AWS. i want to do as the title of this thread says... i want to assign a static IP address to a docker container or some other serverless solution.

i have a ECS instance running on aws, this has a static IP assigned to it because i was able to find the option. this EC2 instance then runs a docker container with a caddy server to serve static content, and manage routing paths and subdomains. suppose i owned "helloworld.com"; i can create a subdomains like "test.helloworld.com" and route paths like "https://helloworld.com/hello/world"

i would prefer not to need a ec2 instance running if i can figure out how to do this serverless-ly. as i mentioned previously, i am new to AWS and i think using pulumi.io exactly fits my requirements and seems to be easy to understand.

... but i cant figure out how to assign a static IP address to a container running on AWS.

i'm new to AWS, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: A static address for *inbound* traffic?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to create it so that I can assign a domain to it... I suppose any static name will work. But I don't know if/how container endpoint can be static.